# SQL Server 2005 foreign key cascade

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table `ParentTable` (`id, Name, town`) and its child table `human` (`mother, father`) in which both columns contain mappings to the parent table.

The parent table has the column `town` which contain foreign key reference with `Town` (`townid, townname`) and that town is added with foreign key reference.

Now the problem is I need to give the cascade constraint for human table, but in SQL Server multiple column for the same parent table can not be given cascade. So I created trigger like this,

```
create trigger DEL_Parent                                             
ON Parent  
instead of delete as      
   set nocount on       

   delete from human       
   where mother IN (select id from deleted)        
      or father IN (select id from deleted)

 delete from Parent where id in(select id from deleted).
```

But when I try to execute the trigger, the system shows the following error

> *Cannot create instead of delete or instead of update trigger
>   DEL_Parent on table Parent. This is because the table has a foreign
>   key with cascading delete or update.*

How could resolve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the query as:

```
create trigger DEL_Parent                                             
ON Parent  
after delete as      
  set nocount on       

  delete 
  from human       
  where mother IN (select id from deleted)        
     or father IN (select id from deleted)

  delete 
  from Parent 
  where id in(select id from deleted)
```

because `INSTEAD OF DELETE` triggers cannot be defined on a table that has a foreign key defined with a `DELETE` action.

Answer (score 0):

INSTEAD OF DELETE triggers cannot be defined on a table that has a foreign key defined with a DELETE action.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208(v=sql.90).aspx

So, I guess if you wanted to you would have to drop your `cascade delete` and handle that with a trigger if you still wanted to enforce it.

Comment: what is the other possibility to achieve?